# Rewrite rules htaccess drive me crazy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a link like

```
 www.mysite.com/order
```

I want when the user enter this :

```
 www.mysite.com/fruit-apple
```

Php do that :

```
www.mysite.com/order?fruit=apple
```

I dont know how to that , is that even possible with `htaccess` or `php` ?

this code just redirect me to /en/order?fruit=apple but i want to keep the 
fruit-apple simply url

```
  RewriteRule ^fruit-apple$ /en/order?fruit=apple [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible with htaccess. What have you tried that's driving you crazy?

Comment: but i get redirected ! how can i keep the  www.mysite.com/fruit-apple url ?

Comment: Actually he was asking you to share with us the code you tried (that seems to redirect you instead of rewriting), preferably in your post with the "edit" link.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your `RewriteRule` directive to actually redirect the request, you need to remove the `[R]` flag. That's what's performing the client-side redirect, rather than just rewriting the URL on the server.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^fruit-apple$ /en/order?fruit=apple [L]
```